# Using SeekBar to Control Volume in android?

Tags: android, volume, seekbar, android-audiomanager

How can I accurately change the volume of my app using a seekbar without controlling the volume by the volume buttons on my android device? I have seperate function on the Volume keys on my android that's why I want to use a seekbar to control the volume. Can Anyone please help me?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11095576/change-media-player-volume-on-seekbar/22039786#22039786

Answer (score 104, accepted):

Please look at below code . It solves your problem.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener;

public class TestExample extends Activity 
{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    private SeekBar volumeSeekbar = null;
    private AudioManager audioManager = null; 

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        initControls();
    }

    private void initControls()
    {
        try
        {
            volumeSeekbar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
            audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
            volumeSeekbar.setMax(audioManager
                    .getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC));
            volumeSeekbar.setProgress(audioManager
                    .getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC));   


            volumeSeekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() 
            {
                @Override
                public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) 
                {
                }

                @Override
                public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) 
                {
                }

                @Override
                public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar arg0, int progress, boolean arg2) 
                {
                    audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                            progress, 0);
                }
            });
        }
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Eclipse is telling me to remove the @Override annotations.. and it doesnt work after I do so. Please help

Comment: This is most likely because you are switching between Java 1.5 and Java 1.6. In 1.5 you couldn't mark interface implementations with @Override, but you can in 1.6.

Comment: I tried to let my activity implement the OnSeekBarChangeListener and re-implemented the methods, but the app crashes on these lines:  volumeSeekbar.setMax(audioManager
                    .getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC));
            volumeSeekbar.setProgress(audioManager
                    .getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC));

Comment: When the user modifies the volume using the device volume control, is there any listener to reset the `SeekBar` to the new value?

Comment: i cant hear the sound of volume changed in android

Comment: @ChiragRaval Do you know how to change Volume Dialog Layout in AOSP? What is layout path?

Answer (score 4):

**@CommonsWare** do it like this in https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/SystemServices/Volume and also set five types of volume using SeekBar

**Handling five different types of Volume**

```
/***
  Copyright (c) 2008-2012 CommonsWare, LLC
  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not
  use this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain a copy
  of the License at http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0. Unless required
  by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software distributed under the
  License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS
  OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the License for the specific
  language governing permissions and limitations under the License.

  From _The Busy Coder's Guide to Android Development_
    http://commonsware.com/Android
*/

package com.commonsware.android.syssvc.volume;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.SeekBar;

public class Volumizer extends Activity {
  SeekBar alarm=null;
  SeekBar music=null;
  SeekBar ring=null;
  SeekBar system=null;
  SeekBar voice=null;
  AudioManager mgr=null;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    mgr=(AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

    alarm=(SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.alarm);
    music=(SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.music);
    ring=(SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.ring);
    system=(SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.system);
    voice=(SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.voice);

    initBar(alarm, AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM);
    initBar(music, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);//for Volume this is neccessary
    initBar(ring, AudioManager.STREAM_RING);
    initBar(system, AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM);
    initBar(voice, AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL);
  }

  private void initBar(SeekBar bar, final int stream) {
    bar.setMax(mgr.getStreamMaxVolume(stream));
    bar.setProgress(mgr.getStreamVolume(stream));

    bar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
      public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar bar, int progress,
                                    boolean fromUser) {
        mgr.setStreamVolume(stream, progress,
                            AudioManager.FLAG_PLAY_SOUND);
      }

      public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar bar) {
        // no-op
      }

      public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar bar) {
        // no-op
      }
    });
  }
}
```

And for controlling only Volume use only
`music=(SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.music);` and  `initBar(music, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);`

Answer (score 3):

This is a custom `View` I've used to adjust the volume level. It works by sliding your finger up, but you could easily change that.

**SliderView**

```
public class SliderView extends View implements OnGestureListener, OnTouchListener {

private int mHeight = 0;

private int mMaxValue = 16;
private float mDelta = 0;
private int mColor = Color.WHITE;
private GestureDetector mGestureDetector;

private OnValueChangeListener mListener;

public SliderView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init(context);
}

public SliderView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init(context);
}

public SliderView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    init(context);
}

@Override
public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
    mDelta = 0;
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
    mDelta = 0;
}

@Override
public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent event1, MotionEvent event2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {

    if (mDelta >= 1 || mDelta <= -1) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onValueChanged((int) mDelta);
        }
        mDelta = 0;
    } else {
        mDelta += mMaxValue * distanceY / mHeight * 2;
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onShowPress(MotionEvent e) {

}

@Override
public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    mHeight = getHeight();
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

    int action = event.getAction();
    if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        v.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(0x33, Color.red(mColor), Color.green(mColor),
                Color.blue(mColor)));
    } else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP || action == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL) {
        v.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    }
    mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    return true;
}

public void setColor(int color) {
    mColor = color;
}

public void setMax(int max) {
    mMaxValue = max;
}

public void setOnValueChangeListener(OnValueChangeListener listener) {
    mListener = listener;
}

private void init(Context context) {
    setOnTouchListener(this);
    mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, this);
    mHeight = getHeight();
}

public interface OnValueChangeListener {

    void onValueChanged(int value);
    }

}
```

**Using it** - make sure you implement `OnValueChangeListener`.

```
SliderView mSlider;
mSlider= (SliderView) findViewById(id);
mSlider.setOnValueChangeListener(this);
mSlider.setMax(mAudioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC));
```

It's not exactly what you're asking for, but it should definitely help you out, I think.

Answer (score 2):

```
private AudioManager audioManager;
private SeekBar seekBarSound;
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        seekBarSound = findViewById(R.id.seekbar_sound);
        try {
        setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

        seekBarSound.setMax(audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC));
        seekBarSound.setProgress(audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC));
        seekBarSound.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i, boolean b) {
                audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, i, 0);
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
 }
```

**sync with volume key:**

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP){
        seekBarSound.setProgress((seekBarSound.getProgress()+1>seekBarSound.getMax())?seekBarSound.getMax():seekBarSound.getProgress()+1);
    }else if (keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN){
        seekBarSound.setProgress((seekBarSound.getProgress()-1<0)?0:seekBarSound.getProgress()-1);
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I added some clear notes for you so you'll understand the logics of every line good luck!

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
AudioManager audioManager;
//start the video when clicked.
public void pButton(View view){
    mediaPlayer.start();
}
//pause the audio when clicked.
public void pause(View view){
    mediaPlayer.pause();
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //definning the audio manager as an audio service.
    audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
    //setting an integer with the value of the max volume of every device.
    int maxVolume= audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(audioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    //getting the current volume.
    int currentVol = audioManager.getStreamVolume(audioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    //setting the audio at the app setup so we wont nned to write this line in every method.
    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.allofme);

     SeekBar volumeC = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.volSeekBar);
          //setting the limit of the seek bar from its default 100 to the device max.
          volumeC.setMax(maxVolume);
          //setting the current value int to match with the seek bar.
          volumeC.setProgress(currentVol);
         //setting a listener to check the seekbar stats at all changes.
    volumeC.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            Log.i("Seek Bar change:", Integer.toString(progress));
            /*setting the audio manager to stream music with the value of the current integer
            from the seek bar*/
            audioManager.setStreamVolume(audioManager.STREAM_MUSIC ,progress ,0);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am having problem of volume set 0 when initialize

I have fixed problem by using below code

```
volumeManager.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i, boolean b) {
                if(b){
                    mAudioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, i, 0);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

**Volume Seekbar with changing Percentage text(100 % )**

create a java class and paste all the below code

```
public class Volume_Dialog extends AppCompatDialogFragment {
private ImageView cross;
private TextView volume_no;
private SeekBar seekBar;
AudioManager audioManager;

@SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
@NonNull
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.volume_popup, null);
    builder.setView(view);
    getActivity().setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    cross = view.findViewById(R.id.volume_cross);
    volume_no = view.findViewById(R.id.volume_number);
    seekBar = view.findViewById(R.id.volume_seekbar);
    audioManager = (AudioManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    seekBar.setMax(audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC));
    seekBar.setProgress(audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC));
    int mediavolume = audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    int maxVol = audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    double volPerc = Math.ceil((((double) mediavolume / (double) maxVol) * (double) 100));
    volume_no.setText(volPerc+" %");
    seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, progress, 0);
            int mediavolume = audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            int maxVol = audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            double volPerc = Math.ceil((((double) mediavolume / (double) maxVol) * (double) 100));
            volume_no.setText(volPerc+" %");
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }
    });


    cross.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dismiss();
        }
    });
    return builder.create();
}}
```

Now call this java class in MainActivity in any onclick method. Thats it

```
Volume_Dialog volume_dialog = new Volume_Dialog();
                volume_dialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "popup dialog");
```