# Android: SeekBar volume control in a AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, seekbar, android-audiomanager

I know how to control sound volume with a seekbar:

```
audioManager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    int maxVolume = audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    int curVolume = audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    SeekBar volControl = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.volbar);
    volControl.setMax(maxVolume);
    volControl.setProgress(curVolume);
    volControl.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar arg0, int arg1, boolean arg2) {
            audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, arg1, 0);
        }
    });
```

but.. I don't know how to do it in a AsyncTask class which show a dialog(with seekbar) while sound is playing... any ideas or examples?

thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10570414/1289716

Comment: You don't have access to the UI thread inside of the doInBackground() method of AsyncTask.

Comment: so.. is it imposible to do? My AsyncTask in preExecute method display a loading.. in doInBackground method start the sound and in postExecute display a dialog in which I want my seekbar volume control..

Comment: why you would do this :\

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11095576/change-media-player-volume-on-seekbar/22039786#22039786 use this it work fine for me