# Set volume using seekbar

Tags: android, seekbar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using SeekBar to Control Volume in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10134338/using-seekbar-to-control-volume-in-android)

How can i set the volume using seekbar in my android application?? I want to accurate the ringer volume from my application rather to set it from phone. Any thoughts ??

Comment: [Possible Duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10134338/940096)

Comment: You can simply try the user [Chirag Raval's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10134544/940096) from this [existing question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10134338/940096) Controlling the volume working based on [AudioManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html)