# playing two mediaplayer objects simultaneously using seekbar adjusting volumes for both

Tags: android, audio, seekbar, android-audiomanager

How can I set the volume of 2 simultaneously playing mediaplayer objects using a single seekbar?

when the seekbar goes to left the volume of one song should increase and volume of other song should decrease.

I tried using the mp.setVolume method for this purpose but no use.
As far as I know, using AudioManager , the stream music is set. This means that if two songs are being played then both the songs would either have an increase in the volume or would have a decrease. Is there any other way?
here's my code:

```
    @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                    boolean fromUser) {
                if(progress==progress--)
                {
                    int volume=volumeSeekbar.getMax()-progress;
                mp.setVolume(volume, volume);
                mp1.setVolume(progress,progress);
                //audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, progress, 0);
                }
                }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show the code for implementing seekbar. How are you incrementing/decrementing your volume?

Comment: it doesnt make any difference as mp.setVolume method does not work only. the volume neither increases nor decreases with the progress of seekbar.

Comment: the volume of the mediaplayer object neither increases nor decreases along with the seekbar's progress. so its of no use.

Answer (score 0):

To use seekbar to control volume in android:

[Using SeekBar to Control Volume in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10134338/using-seekbar-to-control-volume-in-android)

In this function given there,

```
@Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar arg0, int progress, boolean arg2) 
            {
                audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                        progress, 0);
                //Here instead of playing with audioManager, play with your media player objects, by using mp.setvolume() function. Increase one, and decrease the other.
            }
        });
```

Here instead of playing with audioManager, play with your media player objects, by using something like

```
 mp1.setvolume(volume_index,volume_index);  
 mp2.setvolume(-volume_index,-volume_index);
```

Increase one, and decrease the other, and viceversa.

**Note:** You can also *map* progress to volume_index by checking how *incrementally* it increases and then doing the same for volume_index.

Comment: Did you try with those changes I mentioned?

Comment: i even tried using for and if loops...
but i am really unable to do it.