# sound volume not working on Android

Tags: android

I have an app that is producing a sound on Android, my code is setting volume on all audio streams to make sure all streams has volume set. Here are that streams:

```
STREAM_MUSIC
STREAM_RING
STREAM_ALARM
STREAM_NOTIFICATION
STREAM_VOICE_CALL
STREAM_DTMF
STREAM_SYSTEM
```

If I change the volume using:

```
audioMgr.setStreamVolume(audioStream, newVolume, 0);
```

I don't see the volume is being changed, it play the default volume but the touch sound volume is getting changed using above method.
Here is that code:

```
HashMap<Integer, Integer> maxVolumeMap= new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
AudioManager audioMgr = (AudioManager)context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
maxVolumeMap.put(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,audioMgr.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC));
maxVolumeMap.put(AudioManager.STREAM_RING,audioMgr.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING));
maxVolumeMap.put(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM,audioMgr.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM));
maxVolumeMap.put(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION,audioMgr.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION));
maxVolumeMap.put(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL,audioMgr.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL));
maxVolumeMap.put(AudioManager.STREAM_DTMF,audioMgr.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_DTMF));
maxVolumeMap.put(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM,audioMgr.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM));
int newVolume = 7; //this is new volume value
Iterator<Integer> itr = maxVolumeMap.keySet().iterator();
while (itr.hasNext())
{
    //set new volume for all audio streams
    int audioStream = itr.next();
    float deviceVolume = (float)(newVolume/10.0f) *maxVolumeMap.get(audioStream);
    audioMgr.setStreamVolume(audioStream, Math.round(deviceVolume), 0);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A few things could be happening here. First, check your target device doesn't have a fixed volume policy. As outlined in [AudioManager.setStreamVolume()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#setStreamVolume%28int,%20int,%20int%29)

> This method has no effect if the device implements a fixed volume policy as indicated by isVolumeFixed().

Next, make sure you are not setting the volume above the maximum setting. you can use [AudioManager.getStreamMaxVolume()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#getStreamMaxVolume%28int%29) to find that number.

If neither of these are the issue, you'll have to post some code as to how you're using the API.

Comment: Thanks, There is no fixed volume policy set because the touch sound on the screen is working with my code and I can increase or decrease sound.

Answer (score 0):

To manage volume in android please go to below link:

1. http://developer.android.com/training/managing-audio/volume-playback.html
2. [Using SeekBar to Control Volume in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10134338/using-seekbar-to-control-volume-in-android)

   I hope it will help.