# How to set Videoview Volume Programmatically?

Tags: android, android-videoview, android-audiomanager

I have 4 Videoview which is created dynamically. I want to set a custom volume for only one video which is coming from the server, the remaining three videos will be mute.

I want to set a custom volume for particular videos I tried below code it's not working

```
 vid1.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener()
                {
                    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp)
                    {
                     //mp.setVolume(100f, 100f);
                     //mp.setLooping(true);
                     vid1.enableSound(20,mp); //here i will set music sound dynamically
                     vid1.start();
                     playingvideo1 = true;
                    }
                });
                //startTimeForContent = dateFormatForContent.format(new Date());
                vid1.setOnErrorListener(mOnErrorListener2);
                playBackfunction1();
            }
```

---

```
public void enableSound(int sound, MediaPlayer mp){
        Float f = Float.valueOf(sound);
        Log.e("checkingsounds","&&&&&   "+f);
        mp.setVolume(f,f);
        mp.setLooping(true);
        AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, sound, AudioManager.FLAG_PLAY_SOUND);
    }
```

**When I give volume 0 it is working...but when change 10,20,30 video is playing full sound....**

I already research below:

[sound volume not working on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28613587/sound-volume-not-working-on-android?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[Using SeekBar to Control Volume in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10134338/using-seekbar-to-control-volume-in-android)

[How to increase and decrease volume in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38482760/how-to-increase-and-decrease-volume-in-android?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After researching some hours I got a solution

**You need to set Volume 0 to 15**

```
vid1.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener()
                {
                    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp)
                    {
                     //mp.setVolume(100f, 100f);
                     //mp.setLooping(true);

                     vid1.enableSound(10,mp);  //set Volume 0 to 15.

                     vid1.start();
                     playingvideo1 = true;
                    }
                });
                //startTimeForContent = dateFormatForContent.format(new Date());
                vid1.setOnErrorListener(mOnErrorListener2);
                playBackfunction1();
            }
```

---

```
 public void enableSound(int sound, MediaPlayer mp){
        Float f = Float.valueOf(sound);
        Log.e("checkingsounds","&&&&&   "+f);
        mp.setVolume(f,f);
        mp.setLooping(true);
        AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC); //Max Volume 15
        audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);  //this will return current volume.

        audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, sound, AudioManager.FLAG_PLAY_SOUND);   //here you can set custom volume.
    }
```