# Set Volume zero when I click on image1 and set highest when click on image2. how to do this?

Tags: android

[image]

above you can see two Images .
when I click on left side image, Sound become 0
and 
when I click on right side Image ,sound become Highest.

please help me to solve this.

**I had try only this much for seekbar of volume, 
that works well ...**

```
volumeSeekbar = (SeekBar) v.findViewById(R.id.volseekbar);
            audioManager = (AudioManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
            volumeSeekbar.setMax(audioManager
                    .getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC));
            volumeSeekbar.setProgress(audioManager
                    .getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC));


            volumeSeekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar arg0, int progress, boolean arg2) {
                    audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, progress, 0);
                }
            });
```

Comment: Can't provide code writing service. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Besides the linked question, you can also read more about controlling the volume in the [AudioManager docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html)

Comment: How is your whole UI built? Are the Mute- and Max-Volume elements are buttons? Do you have an onClickListener on this buttons?

Answer (score 0):

This post talks about various ways of implementing a volume seeker and I believe it is what you are looking for. [Using SeekBar to Control Volume in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10134338/using-seekbar-to-control-volume-in-android)