# How to increase and decrease volume in android

Tags: android

Hello i am new to android.
I have 2 Imagebuttons. 1 for increasing volume and another for decreasing.
And i have one Seekbar to show increase and decrease levels.
I want an android code to increase as well as decrease system volumes and it should also reflect the Seekbar. Can anyone please help me

Comment: query all ready existed in stackoverflow check this it may help full http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10134338/using-seekbar-to-control-volume-in-android

Answer (score 0):

```
audio = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

        final SeekBar seekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
        Button increaseVolume = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        Button decreaseVolume = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);

        seekBar.setMax(audio.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC));
        seekBar.setProgress(audio.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC));

        seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                if (fromUser) {
                    audio.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, progress, AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }
        });

        increaseVolume.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (seekBar.getProgress() < audio.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC)) {
                    seekBar.setProgress(seekBar.getProgress() + 1);
                    audio.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, seekBar.getProgress(), AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI);
                }
            }
        });

        decreaseVolume.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (seekBar.getProgress() > 0) {
                    seekBar.setProgress(seekBar.getProgress() - 1);
                    audio.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, seekBar.getProgress(), AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI);
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: k i'll try it out thanks

Comment: @iAndroid this is duplicate stack query

Comment: @SuryaBondada So [flag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38482760/how-to-increase-and-decrease-volume-in-android#) it as a [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts), no need to comment twice.

Comment: this is not working